# Gravity Forms in Wordpress 'required' tick-box - no General Tab

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have searched and searched the web for an answer to this...
I installed Gravity Forms Plugin in Wordpress and created a simple contact form.
In the EDIT FORMS section I do not get a GENERAL Tab where I can tick the REQUIRED box. I get only PROPERTIES, ADVANCED and CONFIRMATION tabs.
Do I need a License to have access to make fields in the form 'required'?

Thanks
MaryB

Answer (score 1):

The "Required" setting is under "Rules" on the "General" tab for any field that supports being required. Here's a screenshot:[image]